# Android: Registering a user as administrator in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently developing a blog application in android studio through firebase that lets the registered user add and update and delete posts and I am currently wondering is there a way to register a user as a admin where the admin user is the only user who can add, update and delete post?

Comment: Yes it's possible.. Which auth are you using?

Comment: You can't do it directly from Android Studio. Check docs for solution: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to declare specific users with a specific role, "admin" for example:

You set a security rule like the one below for the data you want to be writable/"deletable" only by an "admin":

```
".write": "auth != null && root.child('admins/' + auth.uid).exists()"
```

And you declare the uids of the "admin" users as children of an "admins" database node:

```
- admins
    -h7yic7LeS123asdfsdgwPrfKZ2: true.     //<- key = uid of a admin user
```